# Swift: Pass parameters for a uicontainerview

Tags: swift, parameters, uicontainerview

I have a container bearing a view (only once) he has a gallery of images with scrollView, I need this gallery is dynamic.

How can I pass data to this container / view once it is loaded?

Already tried by protocol, and passing by below. unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the container as a ViewController and pass whatever you want. For example:

```
let container = self.childViewControllers[0] as! MyContainerViewController

    container.myDataArray.append("Data 1")
    container.myDataArray.append("Data 2")
    container.myDataArray.append("Data 3")
```